# iPhone sometimes fails connecting to cc2564 (Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

We are developing an application where an iPhone should connect to an cc2564 device (Specifically cc2564+msp430f5438), the application should make quick and short connections to send some data. We need reliability in the connection so we need to know if the connection was really successfully or not, and we need a way to connect to the device with assurance.

The iPhone connects correctly to de device most times, it discovers services and works as expected, but sometimes the iphone makes the connection but the callback of discovered services is never called.

We used a sniffer to look at the communication packages and we saw that in those cases the connection package was send but there wasn't any response from the device, the phone tries to retry some version request messages and then stops, as you can see in the image:

[image]

The problem seems to be on the device, we are using the SPPLEDemo sample provided by Texas, and the first function that is called when the connection is established is `GAP_LE_Evenet_Callback`, and when  the problem occurs it's never called. We don't know if somewhere inside the GAP API the device receive the connection message.

Is there some way to debug it or to know if the connection message is received by the device when the error occurs?

Is it a problem on the iPhone (unlikely), or is a problem on the device?

Answer (score 0):

You quoted that

> ..the first function that is called when the connection is established is GAP_LE_Evenet_Callback, and when the problem occurs it's never called..

I'd recommend tweaking (playing) a bit with connection timeouts and Link Supervision Timeouts before consulting the experts who have developed the BLE Device firmware if that is possible for you.

Be assured that whenever a connection is made, the BLE device gets an event (callback) from the BLE stack that the connection has been established.
If that event is not handled the way it should be, then you can conclude that BLE device has some implementation issue.